# atom-typescript updates the .ts file, but changes in html don't update upon save

Tags: javascript, typescript, atom-editor

I just installed atom-typescript. I'm on Windows. Changes in a .ts file are updated when I save the file.  When an html file is changed and I save that file, the update does not appear on the page when refreshed. What am I missing? I've read the atom-typescript docs, but don't see anything about this.

My tsconfig.json file is -

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "declaration": false,
   "noImplicitAny": false,
   "removeComments": true,
   "noLib": false
  },
 "compileOnSave ": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing

You need to disable caching in your web browser (and optionally web server). For starters try "empty cache and hard reload" on chrome : http://www.code-pal.com/quick-tip-clear-cache-hard-refresh-on-chrome/

TIP : `html` has nothing to do with atom-typescript

Comment: Thanks. Due to illness, I have not coded in a couple months. I forgot about clearing cache.  BTW, your atom-typescript is terrific. Thanks even more for that.